# LINQ translates when not part of a property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query like this:

```
var q = db.GetTable<Person>().Where(x => x.Employer.CEO != null);
```

This made up query will return the ID of the CEO of the company a given person works for. This works find and dandy, but if I do something like this, it get the failed to translate to SQL error:

```
public class Person
{
  public bool HasCEO
  {
    get
    {
      return this.Employer.CEO != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to do this and wrap the longer expression within a property so that I don't have to repeat a nested table get:

```
var q = db.GetTable<Person>().Where(x => x.HasCEO);
```

How do I create LINQ properties to achieve my desired result?

I'm using C# 4.0 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  LINQ to SQL works by examining the [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) of the query, and does not delve into the implementation of properties to determine whether a row meets your criteria.

What you can do is create a view in SQL server that dynamically calculates this property, and query that instead of the table.

Comment: Can I make a property that returns an Expression?

Comment: I suppose so, but that would be awfully clunky and would almost certainly violate the principle of least astonishment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Other options include moving to Entity Framework or a 3rd party ORM like NHibernate, which would support this type of query in a less awkward way.

Comment: EF is more restricted than linq2sql and linq2nhibernate is more restricted than EF, So he can't do such a thing in them.

Comment: More restricted how? This is totally possible with L2E: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider

Comment: That technique works with any Expression provider and is effectively  a clean-ish implementation of Mark's own suggestion to make a property that returns an Expression.